# XML-based layout for iOS

Tags: ios, xaml, android-layout, layout

When developing an iOS application (CRUD-like, not a game) one basically has two options:

- use Interface Builder for layout
- layout everything in code

Assume that I don't want to use Interface Builder for number of reasons.

Laying out everything in code is fine except less experienced developers tend to hardcode absolute positions and sizes of everything in code. And amount of code required to properly position everything on screen can be frustrating.

Recently I had a look at Android and Windows Phone SDKs and I really like their XML-based layout engines more.

Is there anything like XAML or Android layout for iOS?

I heard about Auto Layout for iOS 6. Unfortunately, I can't use it because most of the time I have to support iOS 5.0 or even iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [WorkflowSchema](https://github.com/CRedit360/WorkflowSchema).  Its layout support is very basic at the moment, but it's open-source so you could add what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a bit old, but in case it is of interest to anyone - MarkupKit is an open-source project I created specifically to address this type of use case:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It allows you to build native iOS user interfaces using markup similar to XAML or Android. It requires iOS 8 but also supports the new UIStackView class Apple added in iOS 9. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I gave up and started using Storyboards since the time I asked the question, though.

Comment: You can actually use MarkupKit with storyboards as well, if you want. You can design the application's flow (segues and transitions) in the storyboard, but define the views in markup. In other words, MarkupKit isn't an "all or nothing" option. You can mix and match, depending on what works best in your app.

Comment: Argh, I wish I'd come upon your MarkupKit before I rolled my own: https://github.com/nickwah/NWLayoutInflator

Comment: @NickWhite - Glad to hear from someone else who is thinking along the same lines. Shoot me an email if you're interested in collaborating. My contact info is on the wiki: https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/wiki

Comment: @GregBrown Very nice. Always wanted to have the power of XAML in iOS. Your answer wasn't here when I upvoted this question. Glad I revisited it. Is there any road-map for your project? Would love to see bindings.

Comment: @LescaiIonel - Have you visited the [project site](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit)? I'm actually in the process of adding support for [data binding](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/issues/79) right now.